# Cypher query: Is it possible to "hide" an existing path with a "virtual relationship"?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

We are working on a project trying to map a structure like Java code connections with Noe4J 2.1.5. We have succeeded in connecting Applications-Jars-Classes-Methods and can for example get a Cypher answer resulting in:

```
App1-->Jar1-->Class1-->Method1-->Method2-->Method3<--Class22<--Jar2<--App1
```

Now we would like to be able to get the condensed answer to what Jars that are connected like this, "hiding" the existing path above?

```
Jar1--Jar2
```

Is it possible with Cypher to get this result without creating a new Relationship like

```
Jar1-[:PATH_EXISTS]-Jar2
```

We can't find anything related collapsing/hiding paths in the manual nor here on stack overflow

Regards

Christofer

Answer (score 2):

There's basically two ways of going about this.

The first is to explicitly create the new relationship, but I won't talk about this that much because it seems you've thought of that and rejected it.   That method is easy, but more disk intensive (depending on the size of your graph)

The second is simply to query for the path when needed, with a variable length path like this:

```
MATCH (jar1 {myid: "something"})-[*]->(jar2 {myid: "somethingelse"})
RETURN jar2;
```

This will get you what you need, but it requires that this distant path be recomputed every time it's needed.   So, it's easy, but it's compute intensive.

Now, more broadly what it sounds like you want is something like a [graph inference engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_reasoner).   In the OWL/RDF world, people will create ontologies that describe different types of entities, and the relationships between them.  One of the consequences of these relationships is that they can be *transitive* and can have implications on them.  A classic example is that a person is an entity, and things like `motherOf` and `fatherOf` are relationships between.  So if you have a path of `fatherOf` relationships between nodes, i.e. `(A)-[:fatherOf]->(B)-[:fatherOf]->(C)`, the inference engine will return the "fact" that `(A)` and `(C)` are related by family.  This would be a consequence of your ontological definition.   That "fact" wouldn't actually be **in** the RDF store, it would simply be **entailed** by the facts.

In your case, you'd do something like writing an ontology that specified that all of the individual relationships you have in your graph are a specialization of some relationship type (like "related to").  You'd then ask the reasoner if a "related to" relationship exists between Jar1 and Jar2, and the answer would be yes because of your ontological definitions.

OK, so the bad news is that **neo4j isn't RDF and doesn't do this**.  Also, doing this sort of thing is way harder than I'm making it sound; correct ontology modeling is an art unto itself, not unlike logic programming from the prolog world of the 1970s.  But basically, that kind of inference is what it sounds like you're looking for.

What I think you might be able to hope for in some future release of neo4j is something akin to a database "view", or better schema support.   I.e. it ought to be possible to specify that whenever a certain relationship pattern holds, some other relationship ought also be present.

Comment: Wow, Thank you very much @carlodurso for this explanation this is exactly what I wanted and now I know why I should involve an ontology in my future system. I do understand that this is more complex, but now I know in what direction I should look for an answer!